# How to specify a side nav bar in html that fix in place using bootstrap5 and/css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm writing a website that employes side navigation bar that is aimed to fix in position, that don't move when I scroll the in content section. I tried both fix-position in bootstrap5 and css ways, but after setting, the side bar always seem transparent in volume, that the content section collapse leftwards, overlaping with the side bar.

```
<body class="container-fluid row">
  <div class="navPart col-md-2 col-sm-2 d-none d-sm-block border">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column" style="height: 100vh;">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block" href="{% url 'seed_list' %} "><strong>projTree</strong></a>
        <div class="" id="navbarNav ">
          <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active d-flex" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'seed_list' %} ">
                <img src="{% static 'seed/seed_list_icon.svg' %}" alt="alt">
                <p class="d-none d-md-block my-auto">Seeds</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'posts' %} ">
                <img src="{% static 'seed/posts_icon.svg' %}" alt="">
                Posts
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="contentPart col-md-8 col-sm-10 border">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
  <div class="infoPart col-md-2 col-sm-0 border">
    <div class="search">
      <form class="d-flex flex-column row g-2 mt-1" method="POST" action="{% url 'search_seed' %} "> {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="searched">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      {% if messages %}
      {% for message in messages %}
      <div class="alert">
        {{message}}
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

The above is my html code. My expectation would be exactly like the duolingo website, in which its side bar don't move when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The trick is the place of putting position-fixed class tag. It should be one level lower than the top nav div. Other wise it'd collide with other content. In gist, fix the content inside nav segment, not the nav segment itself.